# Why is T(x) = 0 not an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

The original question was:

Answer true or false an provide a short proof supporting your answer of the following statement-

> A linear transformation $T : V \to W$ is an isomorphism if and only if
>   $\dim(V ) = \dim(W)$.

The solution this document has says that for $T: R \to R$, $T(x) = 0$ isn't an isomorphism even though $\dim(R) = \dim (R)$. I am however having a tough time comprehending why this is. Is the kernel not the $0$ vector in this case?

Comment: The kernel is the whole space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MattSamuel That’s not a definition. It’s a statement that the OP is supposed to prove true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphisms require that the mapping be a bijection. $T(x)=0$ isn't a bijection for $R\neq \{0\}$.